# Can anyone explain how/why to use jQuery's CSS hooks?

Tags: jquery, css, hook

I have been looking into jQuery's css [hooks](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/csshooks-in-jquery-1-4-3/), and some that are available on [Github](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks). I have been able to use them to set some styles with jQuery, but as far I understand it, it only gives me an overly complex way to set a css style. I am obviously missing the point... What can I do with them? Can I make Opera support css columns for example? if so, how?
Thanks for your help!

```
$(".sub").css({
            'columnWidth':'120px',
            'columnRuleStyle':'dotted',
            'columnRuleWidth':'1px',
            'columnRuleColor':'#ccc',
            'columnGap':'10px'
            });
```

Comment: +1 : really interesting, i didnt know about those hooks!

Comment: Well how are you using them? Post the code...

Comment: I have not done much with it, but setting some css styles: I added the code to my question, which comes after I imported columns.js, a css hook (?) code I got from the Github repo. I mentioned in my first post.

Answer (score 3):

By adding support for these new or browser specific CSS properties it yes allows you to set then with the $.fn.css() function but it also adds the ability to animate them, which is the main uses for the hooks.

http://proj.jetless.org/AWESOME-TIME/

Comment: Even if this is impressive, I can't help but ask: "That's it? just animation?"

Comment: @Regis no its not just animation. Your example of css columns. You could extend the current cssHook for columns and create support for any browser that doesn't have it natively. Would take some work but the cssHooks let you tap in and extend the $.fn.css() structure.

Comment: Modernizr already provides support for alternative styling, so that can't be all there is... The biggest use of jQuery is to take the pain out of UX interactions, a lot of which depend on animations (slides, fades, calendar data-picking, etc). If you want transitions in IE, then you can use jQuery hooks build a function that approximates the transition.

Answer (score 1):

csshooks is good way to implement the new css3 styles across browsers. You can create a csshook plugin for the border-radius which does feature detection and implemented border-radius differently on browsers that support it. Explains it all right here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of things, these CSS hooks are useful for supporting browser specific CSS properties that the core .css() function does not.